# Suppose v1, v2, v3 ∈V and are linearly independent. Let U={v∈V : v= Σ (from i=1 to 3) aivi where ai∈F for all i and a3=a1+a2}

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose v1, v2, v3  ∈V and are linearly independent.
Let U={v∈V : v= Σ (from i=1 to 3) aivi where ai∈F for all i and a3=a1+a2}. 
Assume U is a subspace of V.

(a) show that v1+v3∈U and v1+v3∈U
(b) find a basis of U

Note: v1, v2, etc means "v subscript 1" and ai, a1, etc means "a subscript i"

My attempt:
Let v1= a1v1+a2v2+a3v3 = a1v1+a2v2+(a1+a2)v3

Let v2= a1v1+a2v2+a3v3 = a1v1+a2v2+(a1+a2)v3

Let v3= a1v1+a2v2+a3v3 = a1v1+a2v2+(a1+a2)v3

So v1+v3 becomes  [a1v1+a2v2+(a1+a2)v3] +[a1v1+a2v2+(a1+a2)v3]

Which becomes 2(a1v1)+2(a2v2)+2[(a1+a2)v3].

Thus, v1+v3∈U.
I'm not sure if I did this correctly. Did inset up v1, v2, and v3 correct?
I am also unsure about part (b)

Comment: next time, try to use the symbols of Math-Jax, they are very usefull and quite intuitive. Then, more people will read your questions because it'll be more clean/clear. You can easily find how to write the symbols on the internet (searching for math codes in LaTeX too). To write "a subscript i" its simply a_i, for example (you have to put this between "$$", like every math symbols you'll use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$v\in U\iff v = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + (a_1+a_2)v_3 = a_1(v_1+v_3)+a_2(v_2+v_3) $

So by this we get (a), because $v_1+v_3 = 1\cdot(v_1+v_3)+0\cdot(v_2+v_3) $ and hence $v_1+v_3\in U$ and $v_2+v_3 = 0\cdot(v_1+v_3)+1\cdot(v_2+v_3) $ and hence $v_2+v_3\in U$

And by what we first did, we have that $\{v_1+v_3, v_2+v_3\}$ generates the subspace $U$, and they are in fact a basis for $U$. Because their linear independence is proved by this:

Suppose $a(v_1+v_3) + b(v_2+v_3)=0$ then we have $a(v_1+v_3) + b(v_2+v_3) = av_1 + bv_2 + (a+b)v_3 = 0$ beacuse of the linear independece of $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ this implies that $a=b=a+b=0$ what in particular gives us what we want ($a=b=0$), proving the linear indepence... Hence it is a basis.